# Adding Items onto Observable Collection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add ontop of a Observable COlleciton.  But When I do it doesnt add 2 distinct records, Instead it just adds 2 duplicates of the latest Records.

```
using (var ctx = DB.Get())
   {        
   var Indepth = from z in ctx.Interactions
         where z.ActivityDate >= start && z.ActivityDate <= end && z.Indepth == true
         select new { Indepth = z.Indepth };
         info.SectionInfo = "Indepth Inquiries";
         info.Result = Indepth.Count();
         QuarterlyInfo.Add(info);

  var general = from z in ctx.Interactions
         where z.ActivityDate >= start && z.ActivityDate <= end && z.Indepth == false
         select new { Indepth = z.Indepth };
         info.SectionInfo = "General Inquiries";
         info.Result = general.Count();
         QuarterlyInfo.Add(info);                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the info object is but you're adding it in both queries:

```
     info.SectionInfo = "Indepth Inquiries";
     info.Result = Indepth.Count();
     QuarterlyInfo.Add(info);

     info.SectionInfo = "Indepth Inquiries";
     info.Result = Indepth.Count();
     QuarterlyInfo.Add(info);
```

that might account for the dupes?

Comment: I am trying to stack both queries, But Im not adding the same information!, You are portraying it as it's 2 duplicated lines. BUT CLEARLY you didnt see it's two different queries.

Comment: apologies, my bad - i meant to copy the second query into text editor.

Comment: I think what RST_7 was getting at is that you're reusing the "info" object and simply overriding its properties on the second query instead of creating a new info object.

Comment: Ahhh That makes alot more sense. Is there a Way to Add it to the Collection, clear it and add another. Or do I have to create a new object everytime?

Comment: I'd create a new instance, might be faster than a double save.